# How to finish around the inside of new windows after replacing old ones

Tags: windows, refinishing

New windows were put in about a year ago and we were left with the result shown in the photos. I'm tired of seeing this and want to fix and finish it myself. However, I'm not sure what steps to take.[image][image]![image]

Comment: Do you have experience with DIY,  do you have the power tools. A little back ground on your abilities would help to get an informed  answer.

Comment: I have some experience with basic DIY. Examples include removing and replacing baseboards and trim, patching small holes in drywall, applying stain and finish to wood projects, painting, caulking. I'm not sure what power tools I would need but have access to a large variety.

Comment: This is a fairly subjective question. Some folks would scrape, fill, sand, and paint. Some would pull the casing and install new jambs, then reinstall or replace the casing (with our without repairing the wall surface). Specific goals are going to be necessary for your question to fit our Q&A format. It's too broad as it is.

Comment: sand, preferably with a power tool sander, then use zinsser B-I-N sellac primer sealer white, top coat with white or other color latex semi-gloss if not happy with straight bin.  Use a paintable latex caulk to fill in big holes & gaps after sanding & prior to painting.

Comment: Sorry for it being too broad. This is my first time asking on a public forum for help. I'm looking to finish it without having to pull all the casings. I am more wanting to either fill, sand and paint or cover with wood (without covering up the entire window frame) and paint.

Answer (score 1):

Get some 1x4.  I'd go with primed fingerboard pine.  Cut to size and install against the metal frame of the new window.  Caulk, Paint.

I've installed windows and then completely hidden the window frame with interior trim such that you only see the trim I installed and the glass.  The frame that holds the glass is hidden with the trim that butts up against it.